# Simple kriging in raster

Tags: python, interpolation, kriging

I want to use a Python script for interpolation in 1st image to have the result of 2nd one, this result is from simple kriging saga. I tried the code below but I have two main problems.

1. Need a lot of time, over 3-4 hours to have
2. The result is this in 3d image and it's really different.

```py
from osgeo import gdal,ogr
import numpy as np
import gstools as gs
import time

#read a 2-D array from image
filefolder="C:/Users/fermi/Desktop/SUEWS/SUEWSapp/kriging/"
rasterinput=filefolder+"T2UFfill_T2_01_14.tif"
src_ds = gdal.Open( rasterinput )
b3 = np.array(src_ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())

# the coordinates of x and y
x= np.arange(322580., 335780., 100.)
y = np.arange(3906895., 3913695. , 100.)
start = time.time()
print("hello")

# your input data as x, y, data points
data = b3
cond_pos = gs.generate_grid((x,y))
cond_val = [1.0]
mean = np.mean(data)
# simple gaussian model since your plot looks rather smooth
model = gs.Gaussian(dim=2,len_scale=1)
krige = gs.krige.Simple(model, cond_pos, data)

# output on a structured grid (image) with specified axis
xaxis, yaxis = y,x
field = krige.structured([xaxis, yaxis], return_var=False)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Simple Kriging is inappropriate for raster data (for both statistical and practical reasons, as you have learned).  What really is your problem: do you just need to interpolate or do you really need to Krige for some reason?

Comment: I want to interpolate, but using simple interpolation, like bilinear or other from warp, has not the result that i want. The 2nd image as you is produced from SAGA Simple Kriging model and it can be produced in less than a couple of minutes. So i m trying to use something similar in python script or a way to use SAGA in a standalone python. I found this library for Kriging and i m trying to use it without result. If there is another way to interpolate image 1 to image 2 i would be glad to hear it.

Comment: There are enormous numbers of ways to interpolate.  Please [search this site](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=interpolat*%20raster) for solutions.

Comment: i tried some of them but i think i need kriging. Because using interpolation the doesn't change the value of the pixel. If you see the 2nd image it has different values. So if you know any way to use kriging i would be grateful for that. Or a way to use saga in a standalone python script could be the solution.

Comment: It sounds like either you aren't interpolating correctly or you need something else besides interpolation.

Comment: i will add you my code below so you can see.

Comment: @whuber for some reason they deleted my comment. Anyway it seems interpolation isn't good for my needs. I would like to find a way for kriging like saga simple kriging tool. Because it uses a moving window and weights to create a new one. If interpolate the image as it is, the middle point of each pixel will have the value but if I use kriging will be different. This way I can clear the artifacts and make it smoother.